# Cron job (python script) not writing json file

Tags: ubuntu, cron, ubuntu-18.04

Ubuntu machine 18.04 running on AWS EC2. 
I have a python script that polls an API and writes the results into a json file in the same directory.
I have set up a cron job that runs it every 5 minutes. 
The problem is that the job runs, I see it in the logs, but the file is not written. When I run the script manually, the json file is written as expected.

Folder and .py file permissions are 775.

Here is the crontab entry (I access it from `sudo crontab -e`):

```
*/5 * * * * ubuntu python3 /home/ununtu/var/www/html/api.py > 
/home/ubuntu/var/www/html/cron.log 2>&1
```

The cron.log file shows expected output from the python script.
`/var/log/syslog` shows:

```
(root) CMD (ubuntu python3 /home/ununtu/var/www/html/api.py > 
/home/ubuntu/var/www/html/cron.log 2>&1)
```

every five minutes.

Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and i was not able to fix it...

In my case i solve it using a python library (BlockingScheduler) and execute it in background process with tmux.

A simple usage example:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler

def test():
    test_write = 'hello'
    with open('logs.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write('test: {}\n'.format(test_write))


scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
scheduler.add_job(test, 'interval', seconds=5)

scheduler.start()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for reply. I wish I could make the cron job work, but if I can't I'll do what you did!